# Multi language full text search including stemming in Django / Python

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, django-haystack, xapian

Currently we use Djapian + Xapian in our Django-based multi-language projects for full text search. In order to use stemming for each language, we create a different search index for each language. Inside Django, we decide based on the user's language, which stemming and which search index to use. That works fine, however, Djapian doesn't seem to be maintained any more and the code breaks up more and more. So we switched to haystack, but haystack doesn't seem to offer that kind of dynamic stemming that we need.

Is there any way of integrating this possibility, either in haystack version 1.x, version 2.x or in any other Python/Django-based backend?

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand it, you can index content correctly, but not search it in with the correct stemmer?  Or are you wanting to change the stemmer when indexing as well as searching?

xapian-haystack will set the stemming language based on `settings.HAYSTACK_XAPIAN_LANGUAGE` by default, however for searching when you have instantiated a `SearchBackend` instance you should be able to set `SearchBackend.language` before constructing a search to change the stemming language.

Note that I haven't tried this at all, I've just looked at [the code on github](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/blob/master/xapian_backend.py#L154).

Also, I should note that, although haystack is great, sometimes it's better to just use xapian directly.  It's well enough documented, and for complex, xapian only features it might be quicker and easier.  Obviously this is not the case if you already have your application, but it's worth doing if you're just starting out. :)

Comment: Hi Sym, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, for getting stemming to work correctly, the index itself must be stemmed, too. For the moment, patching Djapian is the easiest solution, but how long ... :-P I'll have a closer look into raw Xapian and post any good answer I come up with.